# Errors on compiling solution with htmlcxx library

Tags: c++, htmlcxx

I'm working with html so I need a html parser to help me. Htmlcxx library (http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/) is my choice. It looks easy to use, understand.

But it seems to be released for linux, it has many difference files that I don't know what to do to them.  I'm using windows.

Above is my thought about the library. Below is me practise.

According to the sample on the website, we have these lines:

```
string TreeData;
ReadFile("E:\\data.html", TreeData);
HTML::ParserDom parser;
tree<HTML::Node> dom = parser.parseTree(TreeData);
```

And my includes and using directives:

```
#include "lib\htmlcxx-0.86\html\ParserDom.h"
#include "lib\htmlcxx-0.86\html\Node.h"
#include "lib\htmlcxx-0.86\html\tree.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace htmlcxx;
```

The program is definitely simple but I can't compile it. There's error output:
[image]

I don't know what's wrong. Help me please. Thank you.

Update 1:
All files in htmlcxx directory:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you're linking to the `htmlcxx` library.

Comment: Can you give me more detail information?